# WPF textblock events inside contentcontrol of a button not getting called

Tags: wpf, textblock, contentcontrol

I have a simple button with two textblock elements within the contentcontrol tag of button as under. The problem is that the textblock control's mouseup event is not getting called. Instead the onclick even1t of button is getting called every time I click on the textblock controls.

```
<Button>
<ContentControl>
<Textblock x:name="txt1" Text="Tes1-1" MouseLeftButtonUp="txt1_mouseleftbuttonup"/>

<Textblock x:name="txt2" Text="Tes1-1" MouseLeftButtonUp="txt2_mouseleftbuttonup"/>

<ContentControl>

</button>
```

If I place the contentcontrol  tag outside the `<Button>` tag, then the events work however.

Comment: <button>
<contentcontrol>
<textblock x:name="txt1" MouseLeftButtonUp="txt1_mouseleftButtonup"/>
<textblock x:name="txt2" MouseLeftButtonUp="txt2_mouseleftButtonup"/>

</contentcontrol>

</button>

Comment: Looks like the event is already handled by the button. Just try to set e.Handled = false in button_Click event handler.

Comment: tx lukas koten..I tried but ity didn't work...I even tried to set the Z-index propety on textblocks thinking that it might place them higher in the message receiving pipe and might trigger their events but that too didn't work...any other suggestion?

Comment: Did you try MouseLeftButtonDown?

Comment: basically all events are leading to the button_click event only in the first place...the only luck i have had so far is when i place the contentcontrol outside the button ie like this:-
<button></button>
<contentcontrol>
<textblock x:name="txt1" mouseup="someevent"/>
<textblock x:name="txt2" mouseup="someevent"/>
</contentcontrol>

Comment: Handling the MouseLeftButtonDown as suggested in my answer certainly works for me. Of course you need to click on the TextBlock and not outside it...

Answer (score 2):

It is not the way you can start MouseLeftButtonUp event handler for your TextBlocks, but it is the way how you can handle a MouseLeftButtonUp event on your TextBlocks:

```
<Button Mouse.PreviewMouseUp="Button_MouseLeftButtonUp">
    <ContentControl>
        <TextBlock Text="TestText" x:Name="txt1"/>
    </ContentControl>
</Button>

private void Button_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button; if (btn == null) return;

    if (btn.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(btn)) is TextBlock)
    {
        ;//TextBlock MouseUp handler
    }
}
```

Comment: Yessss...a tonne of thanks Rekshino :-). ...it did the job...learnt a new thing today

Answer (score -1):

Handle the MouseLeftButton**Down** event:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click_1">
    <ContentControl>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt11" Text="test" MouseLeftButtonDown="txt1_mouseleftButtonup"/>
    </ContentControl>
</Button>
```

Comment: Why the downvote...? Try the code :) Setting the Handled property to false in button_Click as suggested in the comment above makes no sense at all.